# Не работает WinExec

Tags: delphi

Почему не отрабатывает простая программа:

```
program Msg;          

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdRawBase, IdRawClient,
  IdIcmpClient, ShellAPI;

begin
  { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }  
  WinExec('msg leklerk "Hello!"', SW_HIDE);  
end.
```

Через командную строку команда msg нормально отрабатывает.
Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется "msg " это не имя выполняемого файла а команда? Если это так то чтобы отработало это в WinExec надо делать через cmd.exe :
 WinExec(PAnsiChar('cmd.exe /C msg leklerk "Hello!"'), SW_HIDE);

Comment: Проблема решена. Моя программа называлась так же, как команда (msg), и бесконечно себя запускала.

Answer (score 0):

Если версия 2010 и выше то

```
 WinExec(PAnsiChar('msg leklerk "Hello!"'), SW_HIDE);
```

а лучше использовать ShellExecute, WinExec считается устаревшим уже лет 10